# Securely storing a password locally that is used for web service

Tags: vb.net, security, authentication, passwords, plaintext

I have an application that authenticates against a third party web service by sending a username and password. At the moment I'm typing the password on a winform each time I start the application - but I need it to login automatically.

I'd like to store the username/password somewhat more securely than

```
Dim username as String = "username"
Dim password as String = "password"
```

I understand that I probably won't stop a determined hacker with access to my source code, but storing them as plaintext feels wrong.

I've found some similar questions on here but none that provide me with an answer I can use.

**Edit**: The web service isn't mine, it's an API that requires me to login to use.

Comment: I have a similar issue with my Android app calling a web service. I encrypt the string locally and decrypt on the web server - I'd like to know of any other ways too.

Comment: Is the web service one you control? If so, it seems like the proper solution is to provide a narrower interface to the web service that only allows clients to do whatever your application does.

Comment: @Max I have no control over it. Its just an API that I'm using.

Comment: I deleted my answer.  Sorry about that; I should have read the question a little more carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For client-side Windows apps there is a [`ProtectedData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) class, which

> ...provides protection using the user or machine credentials to encrypt or decrypt data

So as long as user's profile is safe, so are data items protected with this class. However, if user's password is reset (not changed by user himself), all data is effectively lost.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. If I reset my password or moved the code to a different machine, I'd just have to recreate the file that stores the encrypted password correct?